# How to persist "parent" entity when saving a "child" entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, cascade

How can I let Hibernate save the "*parent*" entity e.g. if I have `CarDescription` that comes from a client via `CarDescriptionDTO`.

If I now want to save that e.g.

```
Session session = HibernateSession.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

CarDescription carDescription = ConvertDTO.convertCarDescription(carDescriptionDto);

session.save(carDescription);
```

How can I make sure that a new `Car` entry gets created if `carDescription` does not have a `Car` set at this point? Or is this something I would not want Hibernate to do for me?

**Car.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car extends AbstractTimestampEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5041816842632017838L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    // ..
}
```

how can I make sure that this also creates a `Car` entry?

**CarDescription.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car_description")
public class CarDescription extends AbstractTimestampEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2840651722666001938L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Car car;

    // ..
}
```

Comment: _"How can I make sure that a new Car entry gets created if carDescription does not have a Car set at this point?"_ So, you want a `Car` to be automatically created and inserted into db with all of its fields (except of `id`) being `null`?

Comment: Well if I call `session.save(carDescription)` but `carDescription.car == null` then I want Hibernate to create a new `Car` entry that gets associated with `carDescription`. I am not sure if that is possible and I am not sure if that it's a good idea to do that. Right now I have the  problem that the client sends me `carDescription**Dto**` with `car == null`. I wouldn't know a better way ..

Comment: So all of the fields (except of `id` and `carDescription` if the asscociation is bidirectional) in the car would be `null`? Is that desirable?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Yes that would be okay - it only needs to provide a valid id to `carDescription`. What you don't see above is that `CarDescription` has another fkey `Language` that gives different tranlations. `Car` is just there to indicate "*there is a car*" and provide common information like "color" etc. but those are fine with default values.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Please note that this should only happen if `car == null`. This is not always the case e.g. if I'm just updating `CarDescription`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1) You can create the `Car` in the `CarDescription`'s field initializer:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Car car = new Car();
```

You also define `CascadeType.PERSIST` so that the `car` is persisted together with its `CarDescription`. This way a `CarDescription` will always have an *empty* car by default.

2) You can explicitly create and save the `car`:

```
Session session = HibernateSession.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

CarDescription carDescription = ConvertDTO.convertCarDescription(carDescriptionDto);

Car car = new Car();
carDescription.setCar(car);

session.save(car);
session.save(carDescription);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not good practice. You shouldn't cascade [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/) from [Child to Parents](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/).

A better approach is to always check for the existing entities prior to populating the incoming data.

The flow will go like this:

```
Car car = session.get(Car.class, carId);
if(car == null) {
    car = new Car();
    session.persist(car);
}
CarDescription carDescription = session.get(CarDescription.class, carDescriptionId);
if(carDescription == null) {
    carDescription = new CarDescription();
    carDescription.setCar(car);
    session.persist(carDescription);
}

CarDescription carDescription = ConvertDTO.convertCarDescription(carDescriptionDto, car, carDescription);
```

This way you make sure the `car` and `carDescription` are associated with the current Session prior to populating the incoming data. Just calling persist will not trigger a database row insert, as it needs a flush for that. If you don't issue any query prior to populating your data, the entities will just be scheduled for flushing and propagated to the DB when the transaction commits.

Comment: You're right. It was a bad idea. I still accept Dragan Bozanovics answer since it is answering my question - anyway thank you very much for showing a better approach! +1